# Two-Way Component Parameter Binding on a class in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a class `MealsQueryInputs` that I would like to use as a component parameter with two-way binding capabilities.

All of the demos and sample code I can find are using built-in primitive types and never a class. I can get the [MS demos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-with-component-parameters) to work but I cannot get binding to a class to work. Is it even possible to do this?

My component `FilterSortOptions.razor`:

```cs
using WhatIsForDinner.Shared.Models

<MudCheckBox Checked="@QueryInputs.Favorite" 
             Color="Color.Inherit" 
             CheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Favorite" 
             UncheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.FavoriteBorder"
             T="bool"/>
<MudRating SelectedValue="@QueryInputs.Rating"/>
<MudButton OnClick="@(async () => await OnPropertyChanged())">Apply</MudButton>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MealsQueryInputs QueryInputs { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MealsQueryInputs> QueryInputsChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnPropertyChanged()
    {
        await QueryInputsChanged.InvokeAsync(QueryInputs);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting errors?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't work. `string`s and `int`s work but classes do not

Comment: Define "just doesn't work" - you aren't really describing what you expect to happen or how you measure/test it. Also, show the markup for where you bind something to this component/parameter please.

Comment: _Working:_ Child component updates the parameter and it is seen in the parent's variable that is bound to the component parameter.  _Not working:_ The parent's variable bound to the component parameter is not being updated when the parameter is updated in the child component.  
I provided the link to the docs of what _is_ working when using ints and strings per the samples and demo code.  
Here is me using the child component in the parent component:  
`<FilterSortOptions @bind-QueryInputs="_queryInputs"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Firstly, if your using an object then you are passing around references to the same object.  So when you update the object in the sub-component, you're updating the same object the parent is using.  You don't need to pass the object back in the callback unless you create a noew copy of it.

Secondly, your not binding the mud controls to the object.

Let's look at your code:

```
<MudCheckBox Checked="@QueryInputs.Favorite" 
             Color="Color.Inherit" 
             CheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Favorite" 
             UncheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.FavoriteBorder"
             T="bool"/>
```

`Checked="@QueryInputs.Favorite"` doesn't bind the control to the field.  It just sets the initial value.

I think (I don't use Mudblazor and it's a little different from standard Blazor Form Controls) you need to do this:

```
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@QueryInputs.Favorite"></MudCheckBox>
```

The same is true for `MudRating`.

```
    <MudRating @bind-SelectedValue="@QueryInputs.Rating" />
```

Then the button:

```
<MudButton OnClick="@(async () => await OnPropertyChanged())">Apply</MudButton>
```

can be simplified to this.  You're wrapping an async method within an async method.

```
<MudButton OnClick="OnPropertyChanged">Apply</MudButton>
// or
<MudButton OnClick="() => OnPropertyChanged()">Apply</MudButton>
```

### Original Answer

There are a couple of issues here:

1. `QueryInputs` is a `Parameter` and therefore should never be modified by the code within the component.  You end up with a mismatch between what the Renderer thinks the value is and what it actually is.
2. When the parent component renders it will always cause a re-render of any component that is passed a class as a parameter.  The Renderer has no way of telling if a class has been modified, so it applies the heavy handed solution - call `SetParametersAsync` on the component.

A solution is to use a view service to hold the data and events to notify changes.  One version of the truth!  Search "Blazor Notification Pattern" for examples of how to implement this.  I'll post some code if you can't find what you want.

Comment: I get it but I mainly don't get it. If I use an int or a string as the parameter type, everything works as expected. The parameter can be updated from the child component and that is seen in the parent component just like all of the demos and sampe code show: [Microsoft's Docs on Binding with component parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-with-component-parameters)

Comment: @MattW. - I re-looked at your question and updated my answer.

Comment: Yep, I was not binding correctly :face_palm: I also changed my component code to bind to a local variable/property as you and @mister-magoo recommended. Thanks to you both!!

Answer (score 0):

As MrC said, you should avoid directly binding to the data being supplied as a parameter.

Here is a simple working sample (not MudBlazor) to show the concept

https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QQEnQjaO54LY3MYK35

You bind to a local variable/property and try not to modify the incoming data directly.

#### MyComponent

```html
<h1>MyComponent</h1>

<label for="choice">Choose</label>
<input id="choice" type="checkbox" @bind-value=localValue  />

@code
{
    bool localValue
    {
        get => Data.SomeChoice;
        set {
            if (value != localValue)
            {
                localData = Data with { SomeChoice = value };
                InvokeAsync(ValueChanged);
            }
        }
    }
    ComplexObject localData;
    [Parameter] public ComplexObject Data { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<ComplexObject> DataChanged { get; set; }

    Task ValueChanged() => DataChanged.InvokeAsync(localData);
}
```

#### ComplexObject

```
public record ComplexObject(bool SomeChoice, string SomeText);
```

#### Main

```html
@code
{
    ComplexObject data = new(false,"");
}

<MyComponent @bind-Data=data />

You have chosen @data.SomeChoice
```

Comment: If you want to create a MudBlazor sample using your code, we can work on getting it working.

Comment: Well, that's fun, thanks for the reply!! I'll give it a shot and report back!!

Comment: I marked MrC's solution as the answer since I was not binding correctly but also mostly implemented your example. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can bind class objects to a custom razor component

This is FilterSortOptions component

```
<div>
    <label>Rating:</label>
    <input type="text" value=@QueryInputs.Rating @oninput=@(val=> {
           QueryInputs.Rating=val.Value.ToString();
           QueryInputsChanged.InvokeAsync(QueryInputs);
           }) />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Favourite:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value=@QueryInputs.Rating @onchange=@(val=> {
           QueryInputs.Favourite=(bool)val.Value;
           QueryInputsChanged.InvokeAsync(QueryInputs);
           }) />
</div>

    @code {
    
        [Parameter]
        public MealsQueryInputs QueryInputs { get; set; }
    
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<MealsQueryInputs> QueryInputsChanged { get; set; }
    
    }
```

This is the model to bind, for simplicity Rating is is string type

```
public class MealsQueryInputs
{
    public bool Favourite { get; set; } = false;
    public string Rating { get; set; } = "0";
}
```

Here is the razor page

```
<h3>Rating: @QueryInputs.Rating</h3>
<h3>Favourite: @QueryInputs.Favourite</h3>

<FilterSortOptions @bind-QueryInputs=@QueryInputs></FilterSortOptions>

@code {
    public MealsQueryInputs QueryInputs = new();
}
```